# How to create multiple ChoiceType - Rows in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a multiple EntityType which gets his values from Database as following:

MyFormType.php

```
 private $membersRepository;

 public function __construct(MembersRepository $membersRepository)
 {
    $this->membersRepository = $membersRepository;
 }

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
    $builder
        ->add('trainer', EntityType::class, [
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'class' => Members::class,
            'choices' => $this->membersRepository->findAllByExecutive(),
            'placeholder' => 'Ausbilder',
            'label' => 'Ausbilder',
            'attr'=> array('class'=>'form-control'),
            ])
```

My Repository with findAllByExecutive()

```
 /**
 * @return Members[]
 */
public function findAllByExecutive()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('partial u.{id, firstname, lastname}')
        ->orderBy('u.lastname', 'ASC')
        ->add('where', 'u.executive = 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

and finally my controller to put this values to database

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        /** @var Dienstbuch $dienstbuch */
        $dienstbuch = $form->getData();
        //dd($dienstbuch->trainer);
        $em->persist($dienstbuch);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Eintrag gespeichert');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('dienstbuch.neu');
    }
```

1. Why my method findAllByExecutive() gives me more then my 3 expected Rows?!
2. How i can build 3 checkboxes to every user row? i get only one checkbox to user. I have read many hours, docs, posts but i cant find a solution. I hope you can help me with a link or an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so

```
/**
 * @return Members[]
 */
public function findAllByExecutive()
{
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('partial u.{id, firstname, lastname}')
        ->orderBy('u.lastname', 'ASC')
        ->add('where', 'u.executive = 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setHint(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, 1)
        ->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Although this may be a good answer there is a lack of explanation.